# To whom do environment variables belong?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

From several websites I read that `getenv` is a system call. However I cannot find any reference to `sys_getenv`.

I am trying to understand what "environment variables" are, exactly. Are they part of the kernel or a mechanism of the shell? Digging a little bit deeper I found that `getenv` is part of standard C library. Unfortunately this doesn't help me to answer my original question.

Comment: Related: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342/150988)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you understand the argument list? 
For example, if you type `ls -l foo bar`,
the shell executes `/bin/ls` with an argument list consisting of four strings:

  `ls
  -l
  foo
  bar`

whereas, if you type `ls -l "foo bar"`
(or `ls -l 'foo bar'` or `ls -l foo\ bar`),
the shell executes `/bin/ls` with an argument list consisting of three strings:

  `ls
  -l
  foo bar`

and `ls -l *` might get you something like:

  `ls
  -l
  ant
  bat
  cat
  dog
  etc`
  …

i.e., whatever files are in the current directory.

## Well,

#### the environment is basically just a second argument list.

Perhaps it would be better to say “the environment is a second list of strings,
structured exactly like the argument list, but treated differently.” 
If you look at [execve(2)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?execve),
you’ll see that the `execve` system call takes three arguments:

- char *filename,                                *(the program to execute; e.g.,* `/bin/ls`*)*
- char *argv[],
- char *envp[]

Whenever any program executes any other program, it is basically using `execve`
(possibly via some higher-level function, such as `execl`),
so it is passing an argument list and an environment list. 
The environment list looks a lot like the output from `env`; e.g.,

  `HOME=/home/fred
  USERNAME=fred
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:…
  TERM=xterm
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  PWD=/home/fred/Super_User_files`
  etc…

The executed program can do whatever it wants with the environment list —
look at it (e.g., with `getenv`), modify it, or ignore it —
the same things it can do with the argument list. 
When a program executes another program
with one of the higher-level execute functions, like `execl`,
it automatically calls `execve`
with the same environment list that was passed in to the program. 
And that’s what happens in 90% of the programs that execute other programs. 
But shells let you modify the environment,
and then they use `execve` directly
to pass the most up-to-date user-specified environment
to every program that it runs.

#### TL;DR

Every process contains its environment list in memory,
the same way it contains its argument list and ordinary variables. 
The environment is passed from program to program through the `exec` mechanism. 
Library functions make it easy for a program to pass its own environment
to any other program that it runs. 
(Naturally, environment is preserved (copied) across a `fork`,
just as all other local memory is.) 
The kernel doesn’t really know anything about the environment
except for the fact that it provides a means
for the environment to be passed through `execve`.

Comment: So, I understood that `execve` is part of the libc. Inside this function I will found a real system call which should be `fork()`, is it right?

Comment: No, no, no.  `fork()` and `exec()` (by which I mean the `exec` family of functions) are related somewhat like a left glove and a right glove; they often go together, and they are conceptually related, but they are *not* the same thing.  `execl()` is in libc, but `execve()` is a system call.  `execl()` *calls* `execve()`, not unlike the way the libc function `fprintf()` calls the `write()` system call, and the libc function `sleep()` calls the `alarm()` system call.  You can check by typing `man ` *`foo`*  —  if the man page comes up as `foo(2)`, it's a syscall; `foo(3)` is a library function.

Comment: @fixer1234 — Thanks, but −1: unclear what you're asking; −1: too broad.  Seriously; I said, “Every process contains its environment list in memory, the same way it contains … ordinary variables.”  Can you clarify what more than that you want?  Would it help if I said, “Every process contains its environment list in *user space* memory …” ?  Would it help if I said, “Processes ‘own’ their local memory, and can access it directly, without kernel intervention.  An appropriately privileged process may be able to access another process’s local memory via system calls.” ?

Comment: I reread your answer.  What I was asking is sort of in there, implied by the process you describe.  No fair making me think.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: I’m glad if you found what you were looking for.  I presume you’ve read [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342/150988); and, if you believe that there’s nothing there that answers the question “What are environment variables?”, I don’t entirely disagree.  [user945389’s answer](http://superuser.com/a/787949/150988) perhaps comes closest: “Environment Variables … store various values to allow programs to get necessary OS information, or ‘Environment’ information.  For example, USERPROFILE and MAIL ….”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I would paraphrase it as: “Environment variables are the containers in which processes (programs) receive information about their environment.”  Some of these (e.g., USERNAME, HOME, and PWD) are things that a process could find out by other means.  Some (e.g., PRINTER, TERM, and TZ) are things that cannot be learned so easily.  And some (e.g., LANG, PATH, and TEMP) represent not just information, but directives.  (These categories are necessarily mutually exclusive, exhaustive, or entirely objective.)  But perhaps the question “To whom do environment variables belong?”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  is best answered by an analogy: Environment variables are like family traditions (e.g., “We open one present after dinner on the 24th, and the rest after 7:00 AM on the 25th.”)  You get yours from your parents.  You can change yours, and what you pass on to your children.  You can’t change anybody else’s but your own — not your parents’, and not even your children’s (after they have moved out).  In fact, you generally can’t even *see* anybody else’s but your own (you can’t even tell whether your parents have changed theirs after you got your start).  … … … … …  Any other questions?

Comment: My question was tied to the title of the thread, which didn't seem to be explicitly addressed in the answer.  Rather than directly addressing it (no heading, "Who Owns the Variables"), your answer describes how the process works.  Ownership is implied by the process.  I now understand more about the process, but you made me work for the answer. ;-)

Comment: Nice analogy, BTW.  Consider using it as an intro or closing in the answer for readers attracted by the title.

Answer (score 4):

#### To whom do environment variables belong?

Each process owns its own environment variables.

Notes:

- Every process has an environment block that contains a set of environment variables and their values.
- The environment variables are inherited from the parent process and is a copy of the parent block.
- By default, a child process inherits the environment variables of its parent process.
- A process may choose to pass a different environment to a child process by creating a new environment block and passing this to the child process when it is created.
- It's not possible for any process to alter any other process's environment variables.

---

#### What is getenv

`getenv` is function in the Standard C Library.

> **Name**
>
> getenv, secure_getenv - get an environment variable Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> char *getenv(const char *name);
>
> char *secure_getenv(const char *name);
> ```
>
> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> secure_getenv(): _GNU_SOURCE
>
> **Description**
>
> The getenv() function searches the environment list to find the
>   environment variable name, and returns a pointer to the corresponding
>   value string.
>
> The GNU-specific secure_getenv() function is just like getenv() except
>   that it returns NULL in cases where "secure execution" is required.
>
> ...

Source [getenv(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv)

---

#### Further reading

[`getenv()` source code](http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/3.x/src/sdk/libc/stdlib/getenv.c)

---

**"I am trying to understand what "environment variables" are, exactly."**

See the answer https://superuser.com/a/932191/337631 by [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott) for a detailed explanation from a coding perspective.

Comment: I am cloning glibc to browse the codebase. I want to know what's behind `getenv`. `man` won't help me here.

Comment: I've already linked to the source in my answer, as well as giving you a link explaining environment variables. If you don't yet understand what they are then reading the c source code probably won't help you.

Comment: Ok I see that I got confused again and felt into X-Y issue. `getenv.c` is referring to `__environ` which is declared in `posix/environ.c` and then local to the current process. I don't understand how a process can inherit environment variables from its parent.

Comment: @nowox The man page helps very well here. You can detect a link to `man 5 environ` and there `extern char **environ;` in it, a table that a process inherits from it's parent, and which you can modify too.

Comment: @David, Environment variables are **nothing to do** with shells, other than in that they provide a means to manipulate theirs.  Environment variables are a part of **every process**, copied on `fork()`, and passed to successor with `exec()`.  See Scott's answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, mine was a simplified answer in that respect. I will correct my answer and point to Scott's for the detailed answer.

Comment: An answer even a non-programmer can understand.  Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

`getenv` is part of the Standard C Library. So, in C you would need to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: I will need to see the sources of this function to understand what is behind. How this function can get the information from the shell.

Comment: man getenv will bring up the manual page for it in Linux.

Comment: @nowox See my answer for a link to a version of the source code (I've no idea whether it is the latest Linux code)